# What is the HarmonyOS equivalent of android.graphics.Typeface in Android?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am working on a project creating custom fonts using .ttf files. Android uses **Typeface** class to specify the intrinsic style of a font.

What is the HarmonyOS alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ohos.agp.text.Font** is the HarmonyOS alternative for **Typeface**. Refer following documentation for Usage

https://gitee.com/openharmony-tpc/openharmony_tpc_docs/blob/master/graphics/Typeface.md